# Resize Facebook Plugins (e.g. Find us on Facebook, Like Button, Send Button) for mobile

Tags: css, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I just added Facebook stuff to my web site, http://TheMeditationPodcast.com, and I'm having trouble making it look good on the handheld (e.g. iPhone) version.

The problem is that all the FB stuff is so small when viewing on the iPhone that it is unreadable. I have tried using width & height (in the CSS stylesheet) to resize, but it doesn't actually resize the image, as it does with other images. Maybe I'm CSS'ing the wrong tag?

How can I make these buttons and apps look right in the handheld version of my stylesheet?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of the text and the "thumbs up image" by making changes to the CSS of `.connect_widget_like_button .liketext` and others

Here are the **changes** that I've made to the CSS to make it look a little bigger like this:

[image: Like button larger]

```
.connect_widget td.connect_widget_vertical_center { font-size: 15px; }

.connect_widget_like_button .liketext { padding-left: 20px; }

a.connect_widget_like_button { padding: 4px 5px 6px 0px; }

a.connect_widget_like_button span { line-height: 17px; }
```